# Is there a way to stop Event Grid from emitting empty records in Azure Data explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-eventgrid

I am seeing multiple ingestion failures in our ADX, as most of our parquet files in data lake are empty.

**Error**: BadRequest_InvalidBlob: BadRequest_NoRecordsOrWrongFormat

Event grid is configured with event type Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated. I tried to search for a setting to avoid the event grid from emitting empty files in adx tables, but couldn't find it.

Any inputs on this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of those empty files? How are you doing the data injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't control the way your blobs are written (or your architecture), you can filter the events in the EventGrid by the size of the blobs.

If your event is:

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/test-container/blobs/new-file.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 10,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/new-file.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

I don't know what is the size of an empty file, but let's say 10 bytes as the event above.

You can filter these events in the [EventGrid in the "advanced filters"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering):

```
"advancedFilters": [{
    "operatorType": "NumberGreaterThan",
    "key": "data.contentLength",
    "value": 10
}]
```

Comment: We can't control the empty blobs created in data lake due to some reasons.
Thanks @sheldonzy. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up an Event Grid data connection on BlobCreated events and start creating empty blobs, you will get ingestion errors.
If you cannot control the way your blobs are written, then perhaps Event Grid data connection is not suited for your scenario. Why are you writing empty blobs?